# How to add large text to listview's(detailed) items?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm writing an analyzer,which shows the packets of a specific program.Some packets are very large and the listview shows only the first 15-20 characters :\

This is my code

```
        string __str = String.Join(" ", data.Select(x => x.ToString("x2")).ToArray()); //covert the byte[](packet) to hex string
        string __ascii = AsciiToString(data); //convert the byte[](packet) to ASCII
        if (encrypted) FormMain.PFA(form => form.listViewAnalyzer.Items.Add("S<-C [ENCRYPTED] Blowfishkey = 0xFF")); 
        else FormMain.PFA(form => form.listViewAnalyzer.Items.Add("S<-C")); 
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(__str); //create new item and place the packet as hex string
        item.SubItems.Add(__ascii); //add the ascii variant as substring
        FormMain.PFA(form => form.listViewAnalyzer.Items.Add(item)); //add the item
```

It must be a property that prohibits adding text with more than x lines,but I can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listview will *contain* all the text, you just can't *see* it if it's too long or has multiple lines.

The way that Outlook and things like packet sniffers often work is that the listview is accompanied by a textbox or "preview" window.  You could change your UI so that selecting the item in the listview displays the full details of the item in an outlook-style preview pane.  Then you could have a large multiline textbox and anything else you wanted.  I often do this by putting an object in the `ListViewItem.Tag` property, so that I can retrieve it in the UI and display in the preview when the `ListView.SelectedIndexChanged` event fires.

Alternatively, the preview could be on a dialog that pops up when you double-click.  In fact, make the preview UI a `UserControl`, then you can do both!

Answer (score 0):

> listview shows only the first 15-20 characters :\

Maybe you need to make the column wider?

> It must be a property that prohibits adding text with more than x lines,but I can't see it.

List view items don't wrap text, so technically they prohibit text with more than 1 line

Comment: I cant make it that wider,the packet length is 600 bytes.So I can't do that?

Comment: What would you like to do with the text that's too long to fit in the column?

Comment: I'd like to make it multi line.It may be placed in two lines(items) if necessarily

Comment: Although it's possible to draw the list view text yourself (see the ListView.OwnerDraw property), I don't think it's possible to control the height of items: you're limited to a single line.

Comment: Maybe a full grid control would do what you need, instead of a list view? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx